# Error para dar o deploy no meu projeto no render enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/render/project/src/package.json'

Tags: deploy, build, render

here were my index.js

```
    import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userRouter from './routes/user.route.js';
import authRouter from './routes/auth.route.js';
import listingRouter from './routes/listing.route.js';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import path from 'path';
dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO).then(() => {
  console.log('MongoDB Connected!!');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(`${err} MongoDB Connection Error!!}`);
});


const __dirname = path.resolve();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000!!');
});

app.use('/api/user', userRouter);
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/listing', listingRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html'));
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    statusCode,
    message,
  });
});
```

here were my package.json

```
{
  "name": "real-state-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Fullstack MERN real state application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon api/index.js",
    "start": "node api/index.js",
    "build": "npm install && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.6.1",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

veja se o root directory esta correto, geralmente uso `./`. Se não resolver, veja se há um `package-lock.json` na raiz do projeto. se houver, exclua e faça o deploy

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).